# Arduino JSON library

Tags: json, arduino

I am trying to get a JSON from a URL and store it (using the aJSON library) in a variable. How do I do that? The aJSON GitHub says that:

> To parse such a structure with aJson you simply convert it to a
>   object tree:
>
> ```
> aJsonObject* jsonObject = aJson.parse(json_string);
> ```
>
> (assuming you got the JSON string in the variable json_string - as a
>   char*)

And my code:

```
if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println(F("connected"));
    String request = "GET /v2/data/5c:31:3e:05:fe:2a/last HTTP/1.1";
    client.println(request);
    client.println("Host: api.iot.ciandt.com");
    client.println("User-Agent: Arduino-CIOT");
    client.println("Content-Type: application/json");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
    delay(5);
```

But I can't get the JSON string to be in the variable json_string as a char*.

The JSON would be:

```
{"sensor":{"id":"5c:31:3e:05:fe:2a","name":"Garagem","metadata":{"Base":"CPS","Building":"23B","Capacity":"20","Room Name":"Garagem","Photo":"http://suaobra.com.br/uploads/dicas/garage-ferrari-.jpg","hasProjector":"true","Calendar Id":"a","Floor":"Térreo"},"userId":"100937898336693053236","projectId":4805278667112448,"serialNumber":"TG-20150810-1000000","status":"ASSOCIATED","batteryPowered":false},"data":{"id":5713573250596864,"sensorId":"5c:31:3e:05:fe:2a","updateTime":1439475125592,"content":{"busy":false},"uptime":60000,"battery":100,"firmwareVersion":"1.0","ipAddress":"198.162.8.4","ssid":"IOT"}}
```

Comment: What API are you using for the HTTP request?

Comment: I am including: Ethernet.h and SPI.h

Comment: I just tried a test and I'm getting the error "Sensor does not exist". It was working before. Did the sensor location change?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String body = client.readString();
aJsonObject* root = aJson.parse((char*)body.c_str());
```

I haven't tested it myself, but something like this should work. You'll need to skip over the response header.